# How to know if the player is signed in?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, xbox360, xbox-controller

I was wondering if there's any way to know if the "player" is signed in or not?

Something like this:

```
if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.Two).IsConnected && !Gamer.PlayerTwo.IsSignedIn)
```

So that the controller is connected and it can be used, but the player is not signed in to an account. Something like a guess.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In XNA there is a [`SignedInGamer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamerservices.signedingamer_members.aspx) class with a `SignedInGamer.PlayerIndex` member that should tell you just that if you can get a hold of the `SignedInGamer` object.

To do that, there is the [`Gamer.SignedInGamers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamerservices.gamer.signedingamers%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) static property which contains a collection of `SignedInGamer` objects based on the current state of the system. This is from the [`Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975583%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) namespace.

With this information you could do something like the following:

```
//If player 2 is connected
if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.Two).IsConnected)
{
    //If we can't find a signed in gamer with a PlayerIndex of two
    if (!Gamer.SignedInGamers.Cast<SignedInGamer>().Any(x => x.PlayerIndex == PlayerIndex.Two))
    {
        //Your handling code here
    }
}
```